# Inconsistent data read back when field Float is declared with digits option

Tags: postgresql, odoo, precision, odoo-8, floating

I am using Odoo v8 and spotted a interesting behavior.

When I declare a Float with digits:

```
pension_unit_rate = fields.Float(digits=(16,4))
```

and put

```
<field name="pension_unit_rate" widget="progressbar"/>
```

in its view definition and input data 0.06 into the record and save, data is stored correctly as 0.06 in the postgresql database.

But when I click Edit button, the data read back from database is 0.060000000000000005.

I verified that data in database is correct (0.06) using pgAdmin and with simple inspection of code:

```
    instance.web.form.FieldProgressBar = instance.web.form.AbstractField.extend({    
    template: 'FieldProgressBar',
    render_value: function() {
    this.$el.progressbar({
        value: this.get('value') || 0,
        disabled: this.get("effective_readonly")
    });

    **console.log(this.get('value'))**

    var formatted_value = instance.web.format_value(this.get('value') || 0, { type : 'float' });

    this.$('span').html(formatted_value + '%');

}});
```

It seems like the data stored in 'value' is 0.060000000000000005 which is inconsistent with data existing in database.

Is this caused by numeric data type when using digits option? Is there a workaround or fix?

Thanks in advance~

Comment: If you want precise numbers, you shouldn't be using `float` in the first place: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

The problem is with old version of convert_to_cache function in Float field definition in fields.py. Update the code fixed the problem.

```
    def convert_to_cache(self, value, record, validate=True):
        # apply rounding here, otherwise value in cache may be wrong!
        value = float(value or 0.0)
        if not validate:
            return value
        digits = self.digits
        return float_round(value, precision_digits=digits[1]) if digits else value
```